# HTML5/javascript: Is it possible to access what I've pasted to my clipboard on my mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

When I use some mobile apps on my iPhone (The Pocket app is what I have in mind), they can prompt me to paste the last thing I copied to my clipboard by clicking a button. Can I do the same thing with HTML5? If so, how?

I found information about the Clipboard API, but most of the resources online describe 'click to copy' functionality. I need a mobile website to read my clipboard and 'click to paste'.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible, because allowing javascript to read the users clipboard seems like quite a security vulnerability. Clipboard content can be sensitive information.

Comment: Yeah even on a normal site I think it's only possible to accomplish this task with actionscript/flash which definitely won't be possible on iOS

Comment: As an aside, this is a bad idea from a user-experience stand-point. Your users can *already* copy and paste in a consistent way across all applications using the UI built into their operating system. You don't need to (and shouldn't) provide them with a "better" way of pasting that only your app supports.

Comment: I was afraid this was something only possible in native apps. thanks everyone! @meagar: since i've only built a responsive web app so far and not a native app, i want some way to post content to my app that is as easy as the integration that native apps have to mobile browsers. I see your point though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry a framework-reliant answer, but it looks like the easiest way you can access the native phone clipboard is with [Angular and Ionic/ngCordova](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/access-native-device-clipboard-ionic-framework/).

For pasting what's currently on the device clipboard, you could do something like this:

```
module.controller('PasteCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaClipboard) {
  $cordovaClipboard
    .paste()
    .then(function (result) {
      // success, use result
    }, function () {
      // error
    });

});
```

Comment: ahh, thanks for your response! Unfortunately I'm using Ember, but in any case it looks like I need Cordova to access the phone clipboard anyway, and can't do it in a web application in a mobile browser, correct?